# Parse single file for SSI

Tags: apache, server-side-includes, ssi

I want to parse a single file (named footer.html) for SSI from my httpd.conf file.

How and where do I do this?

In the default directory I have options + IncludesNoExec, XBitHack on etc. Everythign works, just need to get it to work for this individual file.

This is for a piece of coursework for uni, and has to be done as explained, not via any other method.

Cheers!

Comment: I really think you should rewrite your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/www/common/footer.html
```

Answer (score -1):

Read up on Apache's mod_include module: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_include.html